# Zero KeyFrame animation generated by factory, works on direct instantiation

Tags: java, animation, libgdx

Class to define and contain a libgdx Animation:

```
public class ScreenObject {
    protected int width;
    protected int height;
    protected float stateTime;
    protected String spriteSheetFile;
    protected int spriteSheetCOLS;
    protected int spriteSheetROWS;
    protected float frameDuration;
    protected Texture spriteSheet;
    protected TextureRegion[] frames;
    protected Animation animation;

    public void makeAnimation() {
        spriteSheet = new Texture(spriteSheetFile);
        TextureRegion[][] temp = TextureRegion.split(spriteSheet, width, height);
        frames = new TextureRegion[spriteSheetROWS * spriteSheetCOLS];
        int index = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < spriteSheetROWS; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < spriteSheetCOLS; j++ ) {
                frames[index++] = temp[i][j];
            }
        }
        animation = new Animation(frameDuration, frames);
        stateTime = 0;
    }
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
        TextureRegion currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
        batch.draw(currentFrame, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

If I make this class abstract and extend it to TestScreenObject, I can set all the attributes in the constructor then call makeAnimation() and everything works just like I would expect.

If however I use a factory class that dynamically sets the attribute values using setters and returns the ScreenObject to a ScreenObject[] array, and then call makeAnimation() on the ScreenObject by referencing the array index:

```
    sof = new ScreenObjectFactory();
    planets = new Planet[] { sof.randomPlanet() };
    planets[0].makeAnimation();
```

I get a division by zero error on my draw() call:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation.getKeyFrameIndex(Animation.java:142)
```

The KeyFrames array for the Animation has no frames in it! But this is boggling my tiny little mind. I have verified that the ScreenObject generated by the factory and stored in the ScreenObject[] array has had appropriate values set by the setters, and then I call the same makeAnimation() method that uses those values to make the animation... but it only works one way and not the other.

I've tried searching for other issues with an ArithmeticException on getKeyFrame(), and for what effect the two different methods of creating my ScreenObject class might have, but I'm really at a loss here.

Comment: My best guess is that somewhere along the way, `spriteSheetROWS` or `spriteSheetCOLS` gets set to zero or is never changed from its default of zero.

Comment: Yep. Both setters we setting the columns variable. When I tested the setter methods I used C&P, which in reflection I guess I probably shouldn't do. Ever. Thank you so much.